# Culture on a single continent world

Tags: internal-consistency, society, culture

So, in the process of designing a world, I realized that because the world has only one (given very large) continent. Just making sure as I'm not very experienced in the spread of culture, would there really be a large difference in the lifestyles/cultures in the cities of my world?

Comment: Is there a big difference in cultures of, say, Copenhagen, Nairobi, Tashkent, Seoul, and Pnomh Penh? They are all on one very large (convoluted) landmass....

Comment: Let's consider a familiar example of a large continent, namely Eurasia. I'd say that around 1800 there was a remarkable difference between the lifestyle and culture of Paris, Constantinople, Moscow, Calcutta and Peking... The same around 1700, and 1600, and 1200, and 800, and 100 AD and so on. In fact, I'd say that even today there is a remarkable difference between the lifestyle and culture of Paris, Calcutta and Peking.

Comment: This will depend entirely on your in-world history and the cultures you present, as such it's a story-driven element that's really out of the scope of this forum. I can give you a very broad hint though which is to consider carefully your continent's history of empire, and look at how far spread Latin root language is in the modern world, this may give you stepping off point.

Comment: Throw in a few impassable mountains or deserts to explain the apparent need for isolation.  The other comments are right about the historic precedent of cultural distinction in the absence of geographical isolation.  Even today, New Orleans is culturally distinct despite being served by multiple highways and airports.  But to keep your reader from questioning the logic of your world, throw in an easy explanation or two.

Comment: Your first sentence seems incomplete. You say "because the world has only one continent." Then END the sentence. It feels like you want to describe the problem there, but forgot to put it in. Like maybe you were going for: "because the world has only one continent, there would be cultural issues" or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there would be different cultures.

**Other factors would cause the cultures to diverge, like climate, flora, and fauna.** Some parts of your continent will be hot, others cold, and others will have seasons. Living in a desert vs living in remote mountains of lush forests vs vast plains. Dealing with dangerous wildlife, or abundant fishing or simple lack of any real animals to hunt or raise. All these would affect how the people of that area live and how their culture develops.

**Natural barriers would also cause people to develop different and remain different.** Large mountain ranges, massive dense forests or deadly deserts will all keep people isolated and developing their own cultures that may not mix. Assuming the rest of the world is ocean, the people by the water would develop maritime lifestyles with a bit more freedom to travel around.

Answer (score 1):

There could definitely be a difference in culture. The main differences I can think of would be geography based.

In real life, many cities by oceans and rivers have been areas with lots of activity and urbanization. Think Seattle, New York, and New Orleans. These areas are pretty densely populated. Contrast that with areas of farmland, where populations can be more spread out.

I think geological features like mountains, valleys, and desert could play a role in splitting up different cultures. If it is hard for different cultures to meet, interact, and trade there could be less cultural overlap.

A lot of this will depend on the design of your continent, but I hope this is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

As the other people have said, there absolutely will be different cultures. However, there might be more uniformity than we have here on Earth.

Earth is dominated by large Eurasia + Africa landmass. Because this landmass is difficult to traverse, history of human development is marked by several separate "exoduses" from Africa. These events gave rise to human subspecies like Neanderthals and various races. If there is one large continent with easy migration paths, **there may be no case for the development of distinct races**. People's skin color would just gradually get more brown to the south and more white to the north.

As the history progressed, at some point humanity became advanced enough to travel around the globe. This has brought new species as well as new diseases to different continents. In a single-continent world **there will be no effect of "broken quarantine"**. Species will get more or less distributed earlier in history, and diseases would take their toll through centuries instead of delivering single mortal blows.

By the time of colonization, there will be much less indigenous people around, and much less land suitable for colonization. **Countries like US and Australia are never going to rise**. Subsequently, there would be less original culture that can be studied and preserved.